# Rails unsubscribe link with ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have an Email Model for users to sign up to receive email notifications when a article is added or updated.  The email works properly but I'm receiving an error message with the unsubscribe method I've generated in my email.rb file.  I found the unsubscribe solution within another stackoverflow question that was posted in 2012 but I'm not seeing how to work the solution correctly.

**Email Model:**

```
    class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :email, uniqueness: true
      validates :email, presence: true

      def unsubscribe
        Email.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(permissions: false)
      end
    end
```

**Article Model:**

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      has_many :emails

      after_create :send_new_notifications!
      after_update :send_update_notifications!

       def send_update_notifications!
        email = Email.where(permissions: true)
        email.each do |email|
           UpdatedArticleMailer.updated_article(email, self).deliver_later
         end
       end

      def send_new_notifications!
        email = Email.where(permissions: true)
        email.each do |email|
          ArticleNotificationMailer.new_article(email, self).deliver_later
        end
      end
    end
```

**Unsubscribe link in updated article email:**

```
        <%= link_to "Unsubscribe", email_url(@email.unsubscribe) %>
```

**Error message:**

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Email:0x007ff5c2955e88>
  def unsubscribe
   Email.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(permissions: false)
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call params from a model.  But moreover, you are calling the unsubscribe function while generating the view, which I don't think was our intention. Your setup should be:

In `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :emails do
  get :unsubscribe, on: :member
end
```

This gets you a proper route to hit from your views.

In `app/controllers/email_controller.rb`

```
def unsubscribe
  email = Email.find params[:id]
  email.update_attributes(permissions: false)
  ... { handle errors, redirect on success, etc } ...
end
```

This handles flow of control.

In the view, the link becomes:

```
unsubscribe_email_url(email)
```

Essentially, the unsubscribe method moves to the controller.  Should be pretty straightforward.  Note that this call just generates the URL to be invoked when a user clicks the link, it doesn't actually make the call.  Your current code is making the call.

Comment: Regarding :member, is this something I declare e.g. email or is this something from rails?

Comment: I think this worked, but I'm seeing a template error.  I'm assuming that's because I have not set the handle errors, redirect on success, etc within my unsubscribe method?

Comment: Right, you need to have a view called unsubscribe.erb, or redirect it on success.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explaining what one should do to accomplish this task!

Comment: `:member` is a Rails routing method that defines an additional route on a RESTful resource (like show, index, edit, destroy, etc).  Routes like show and edit are "member" actions -- that is, they act on a particular instance of the resource (in this case, a single email).  There are also routes like index which act on all resources; these are "collection" actions.  Declaring a member route also gets you resource methods; that's why `unsubscribe_email_url` works.

Answer (score 1):

`params[:id]` is only available in the controller.

Your `link_to` also doesn't make sense, it looks like you are trying to route to your model, those are not route-able. It should be a link to a controller action such as `EmailsController#Unsubscribe` and that URL will need an ID of some sort.

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  def unsubscribe
    if email = Email.find(params[:id])
      email.update_attribute(permissions: false)
      render text: "You have been unsubscribed"
    else
      render text: "Invalid Link"
    end
  end
end
```

This does not take into account that you might want to use a token instead of an ID, in that case, see this article for using a MessageVerifier.

http://ngauthier.com/2013/01/rails-unsubscribe-with-active-support-message-verifier.html

Comment: This answer is incomplete, as the view code is preventing anything from working anyway.  But this seems like something to be done in the controller instead of the model...

Comment: I think you're right. The model shouldn't have an unsubscribe method at all. It's not really business logic.